# Implement custom message in Android Studio

Tags: ros-kinetic, message, rosandroid, rosjava, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

at the moment I am developing an Android application that publishes data into a ROS environment. For this, I use rosandroid-core which is included with Maven from the following repository: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo.

By commands like

> compile 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:std_msgs:0.5.11'

I am able to generate all standard messages that are defined in the repository. The String-message is defined like the following:

> package std_msgs;

> import org.ros.internal.message.Message;

> public interface String extends Message {

> ```
> public static final String _DEFINITION = "string data\n";
> ```

> ```
> public static final String _TYPE = "std_msgs/String";
> ```

> String getData();

> ```
> void setData(String str);
> ```
>
> }

Now I want to create my own message type. So I created a Java interfaces that extends the org.ros.internal.message.Message class.

When I initalize a message from the custom type in the code, everything is fine. But as soon as I want to publish a message from this custom message type, I get a NoClassFoundException.

Do you know where the error is?  How can I include the compilation of my custom message type in the Gradle file?

Thanks and best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321503/implement-custom-message-in-android-studio/) by [MrNicolas3003](https://answers.ros.org/users/40955/mrnicolas3003/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

That's not how ROS messages work in Java. Note that those interfaces are just empty placeholders; the actual objects that you use to exchange data are generated in runtime.

Those interfaces are generated automatically if you source `genjava` when building inside a catkin workspace. The standard [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) to create messages applies.

You can check [rosjava_messages](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_messages) repository for reference. It should help you creating custom messages.
If you want to use the messages in Android Studio:

- Create a ROS package with message definitions in your workspace. Configure your `CMakeLists` file to generate the workspace.
- Generate the message artifacts by building the workspace. You will need to have `genjava` installed.
- Source the workspace.
- Launch Android Studio. The Maven paths will enable the IDE to find the artifacts you've just generated in the step above.

Hope it helps!

Extra: I don't have a complete example at hand for messages, but generating service interfaces is analogous. You can check how it's done for services here: https://github.com/jubeira/rosjava_srv_test

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrNicolas3003](https://answers.ros.org/users/40955/mrnicolas3003/) on 2019-04-23**:
Hello,

thank you for your fast answer! Is there also a way to generate custom ROS messages in Java without a ROS environment?

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2019-04-23**:
Hmm not that I know of nor I would recommend... In any case you'll need `genjava` to translate the `msg` files to the interfaces.

**Comment by [MrNicolas3003](https://answers.ros.org/users/40955/mrnicolas3003/) on 2019-04-24**:
Okay, I am going to install a ROS environment. Thank you very much!